# Flutter Google maps Markers incorrect size on iOS

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, flutter

The size of the markers on the map look different on iOS than android. I have tried several things, and the only thing that worked for me was changing the bitmap file of the google map plugin.

```
 return BitmapDescriptor._(<dynamic>[
  'fromAssetImage',
  assetBundleImageKey.name,
  4.0, // <= Replace 'assetBundleImageKey.scale' by '4.0'
]);
```

Is there a way to control the size of the asset? I tried modifying the image configuration size but this had no effect on either platform.

Secondary question, my marker is a simple circle with text in it. Is there a way to draw the circle and text with code and create a bitmap from that?

EDIT: I solved this issue by recreating all of the assets with the desired resolution and a 2x and 3x file. I generally do this working with Xcode and swift, but I inherited this project and the original assets did not include 2x or 3x.

Comment: For me, the markers are correctly sized on Android but humongous on iOS. You can create a widget and turn that into a bitmap.

Comment: Me too. I fixed the issue by redoing all the assets in the app and including a 2x and 3x file. I will edit my post to show the solution I used:) 

I will keep your solution in mind if it comes up again, I was having problems getting iOS to respect the size constraints of the bitmap, so it makes sense that creating a widget would solve this issue as I could just create the circle with text and map it.

Comment: Please see: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100997

Comment: i faced this issue too. Is it possible to solve this by not having 2 files mentioned by @ekrenzin ?